# How to preserve spaces in text input field when echoing php variable

Tags: php, html

I've got:

```
<input type="text" name="location" value=<?php echo $cand['location']; ?>>
```

When `$cand['location']` is something like "East London", the textbox just says "East" and ignores anything after the first space.

How can I have a text input hold echoed strings with spaces in it?

Comment: missing quotes in the hrml for value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved:

```
<input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $cand['location']; ?>">
```