# PHP/HTML - How to retain spaces in form input names?

Tags: html, post

I have a form that has an input `type=text` and the `name` attribute has spaces in it.

When the form submits (it uses `post`) how can the spaces be retained, currently it replaces the spaces with underscores `_`

Comment: Are you sure that it is replaced with `_`? I would rather expect it to be replaced with `+` which is the space separator when url encoding.

Comment: yes agreed, its strange that it did that, it seems to be doing underscores

Comment: Could there be some javascript running on your page that does that before submitting the form to the server?

Comment: That is how php works, also why would you want that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve spaces in text input field when echoing php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287646/how-to-preserve-spaces-in-text-input-field-when-echoing-php-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use arrays in the input names.

```
<input name="data[hello world]" type="text">
```

Then get the data in PHP using the 'data' key:

```
$_POST['data']['hello world']
```