# Using post method with two word in input's name

Tags: php

I made a website but now i noticed if i use two words in form input's name , input's value not sending.
i can't change my algorithm because i have very long codes so my only solition is to make the post method work when it is 2 words so for this i writed short code with similar problem like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="two words">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

there is no answer on php:

```
echo $_POST["two words"];
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and see what keys are there.

Comment: i saw my input value coming but spaces become downstroke.On my website , input's names coming from my database and i using this input's names to change database so "_" breaks my algorithm.

Comment: Now you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks , and do you know any solution to remove theese downstrokes?

Comment: Why do you need to remove them? Use them. Replace spaces with `_` and access this key.

Comment: can you show us a bit of your algorithm?

Comment: Because i comparing this names with databases values and my input's names occurs automatically with another database table so i need to keep the originality of the input names.

Comment: i solved problem change spaces to underscores with "str_replace" , like this one: $variable[$post_a] = str_replace(" ", "_", $variable[$post_a]);

Answer (score 0):

Very basic & yet pretty interesting question. Here are my findings:

HTML(name attribute)  ->  PHP(its name in `$_POST` or `$_GET`)

> ```
> "My Input" -> "My_Input"
> "My&#32;Input" -> "My_Input"
> "My+Input" -> "My+Input"
> "My-Input" -> "My-Input"
> "My%20Input" -> "My%20Input"
> "My&nbsp;Input" -> "My\u00a0Input"
> ```

So, it looks like no space is allowed, however, [there's an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34464498/9430588) that provides a hack in case you really do want to have a space in the name.

HTML:

```
name="data[My Input]"
```

PHP:

```
// Inside $_POST
"data" => ["My Input" => "Joe"]
```

Here is [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092455/9430588) that explains the observed behaviour.

However, until you are not forced to work with `$_POST` for a very specific reason, you may simply use & safely modify another array. For instance:

```
// Hard copy $_POST
$postData = $_POST;
// Keys with spaces are allowed
$postData['My Input'] = $postData['My_Input'];
// Unset keys you don't like
unset($postData['My_Input']);
```